# Sticky cache in Angular2

Tags: angular

I am working on an Angular2 application, and testing it in:

```
Google Chrome Version 54.0.2840.71 m (64-bit).
```

One thing I noticed is that the pages I "return back to" with my browser, are rather sporadic and unpredictable.

i.e Here is a scenario:

- Say I have a homepage of localhost:3000/param1/something
- I click an href using a script hat generates it as follows:

  ```
  <a [routerLink]="['/param2/', myParamValue]">{{showMeTheVlaue}}</a>
  ```
- My url now changes to localhost:3000/param1/something/param2/cows
- I click back in my browser, and the url does not change to localhost:3000/param1/something

The problem that I am experiencing here is that the back button is returning me back to cached versions of localhost:3000/param1/something/param2/cows, instead of localhost:3000/param1/something.

I added some console statemnts to my onInit methods to determine what the problem could be. Here is some sample code:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    someResponse: MyResponse;
    responseSub: Subscription;
    paramsSub: Subscription;

    constructor(private _service: MyService, private _route: ActivatedRoute) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("### we are creating");
        this.paramsSub = this._route.params.subscribe(
            (param: any) => {
                someParam = param['param2'];

                this.someResponseSub = this._service.getData(someParam).subscribe(
                    data => this.someResponse = data,
                    error=> console.log(error)
                );
            }
        );
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        console.log("### we are deleting");
        this.paramsSub.unsubscribe();
        this.responseSub.unsubscribe();
    }

}
```

When going from param1/ to param1/something/para2/* multiple times, eventually I will cause my back button to keep taking me on a loop of param/something/param2/* results. My ngOnDestory is then not called.

Any idea as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The question addresses the problem in the wrong way. It has nothing to do with cache, this is how the router works, it reuses route component. This is [a subject to change](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7757#issuecomment-236737846).

Comment: @estus so what can i do to solve the issue? surely, there has to be a way to get it to stop going all over the place

Comment: The least troublesome way is to assume that route component is not reloaded (and thus ngOnDestory is not called) when params are changed and stick to observables for params, resolvers, etc. If you have problems with URL changes when pressing back button, please, provide a plunk, but there is a high probability that it is a bug.

Comment: @estus can you provide an example please

Comment: It seems that you already do this by subscribing to `params`, so I would expect it to work as expected.

Comment: @estus what can cause the stickyness? maybe I am implementing it incorrectly?

Comment: It's look ok to me. Please, provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to replicate the issue.